perl formatting text with comma youtube transcribe service
If you go to youtube and hit the transcribe button, for some videos, youtube has a transcription service, you can see the whole video text on the right side. If you download it to a text file, it comes in this format. I want to separate the timestamps from the text.
0:12 
well good morning everybody thank you for joining us here at the National Shrine of the 
Divine Mercy it is
0:18 
Vietnamese day and uh we're glad that you could join us uh I have a strong tie 
0:24
to the Vietnamese people my father obviously serving in Southeast Asia being in Vietnam and uh my uh Seminary
0:31 
time I went to Seminary with a lot of the Vietnamese sisters so praise be to God uh we're glad you're with us and
0:38 
today's topic really is so important and I'm coming from a aspect of a personal

I want is formatted like this so I can put it in to and excel sheet, and separate the timestamps if needed.
0:12, well good morning everybody thank you for joining us here at the National Shrine of the Divine Mercy it is
0:18, Vietnamese day and uh we're glad that you could join us uh I have a strong tie
0:24, to the Vietnamese people my father obviously serving in Southeast Asia being in Vietnam and uh my uh Seminary
0:31, time I went to Seminary with a lot of the Vietnamese sisters so praise be to God uh we're glad you're with us and
0:38, today's topic really is so important and I'm coming from a aspect of a personal

the time stamps will go out to this
1:35:35
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    die "Usage: $0 input_file output_file\n";
}
my ($input_file, $output_file) = @ARGV;
open(my $in, '<', $input_file) or die "Cannot open input file '$input_file': $!";
open(my $out, '>', $output_file) or die "Cannot open output file '$output_file': $!";
my $timestamp = '';
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    chomp $line;

    if ($line =~ /^[0-9:]+$/) {
        # Line is a timestamp
        $timestamp = $line;
    } elsif ($line =~ /\S/) {
        # Line is text and is not empty
        print $out "$timestamp, $line\n";
    }
}
close($in);
close($out);

print "Formatting complete. Output written to $output_file.\n";

I wrote the script above, however the file is coming out like this.
and it should not be
, 0:12
, well good morning everybody thank you for joining us here at the National Shrine of the Divine Mercy it is
, 0:18
, Vietnamese day and uh we're glad that you could join us uh I have a strong tie
, 0:24
, to the Vietnamese people my father obviously serving in Southeast Asia being in Vietnam and uh my uh Seminary
, 0:31
, time I went to Seminary with a lot of the Vietnamese sisters so praise be to God uh we're glad you're with us and
, 0:38
, today's topic really is so important and I'm coming from a aspect of a personal

I tried this as well
sed 's/^\([0-9:]*\) \(.*\)$/\1\:\2/'


Is Divine mercy it is really on its own line in the input file, or is it part of the previous line? Because I don't see how your script is merging those lines.

I suspect your input file has CRLF newlines. You're not removing the \r characters.

It might be helpful to show what your input data file looks like??

The problem is with both of your reg ex lines: $line =~ /^[0-9:]+$/.  timestamp is never captured in your logic and \S mean The string contains non-whitespace characters.  Fix your reg ex and it should work. Show your input data and the problem can be solved

@GoinOff The capture is not required, as the timestamp is printed on non-numerical lines. Which will work as long as the timestamp comes every other line. That is not the case with the current input, but that might be due to lack of communication from the OP.

@Barmar If the timestamps ended with \r there would not be a comma on every line, and all the timestamps would be overwritten. There is something more complicated going on.

Try capturing timestamp correctly with my $pattern = qr/^\d+:\d+$/;

@GoinOff The input data file is at the top of the question.

Sorry about that, I didn't scroll up far enough...Oooops

Just repeating myself here but the only reason that each line of output starts with a ',' is because timestamp is never set.

Depending on what your actual input is, the solution could be as simple as:
perl -pe'chomp if /\d\s*$/' input.txt > output.txt

Simply check if a line ends with a number (and optional whitespace), if so remove the newline. And just print everything. Perl will read the input file, and shell redirection will direct the output.
Now you may have something more complicated that you have not yet shown us. You might discover new things if you print your input file with Data::Dumper's useqq option:
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper <$inputfile>;

You might also make the input more readable by inserting space and comma, for example
perl -pe's/\s*\n/, / if /\d\s*$/'


You're using a unix build of Perl, but you have Windows line endings (CRLF) instead of unix line endings (LF).
Convert your file using the dos2unix tool first, or convert the lines yourself using s/\r//.

When the line matches \d+:\d+ followed by a Line Feed, simply replace the Line Feed with a comma and a space (, ). Then print the possibly-modified line.
As a one-liner:
perl -pe's/^\d+:\d+\K\n/, /'

As a script:
while ( <> ) {
   s/^\d+:\d+\K\n/, /;
   print;
}

If you want to accept Windows and unix files without converting, use \r\n instead of \n in these.
If you want to accept Windows and unix files, and produce a unix file, just add s/\r//; to these.

this works until the time goes from to  59:53 to 1:00:06 once there is three semicolons it breaks down

@capser, Adjust as needed. I can only go by the info the OP provided.

The short analysis is, that the test
if ($line =~ /^[0-9:]+$/) {

fails. That may be cause by the Windows way of terminating, or there may be spaces or tabs after the timestamp. You can either opt for a more simple pattern
if ($line =~ /[0-9:]+/) {

where there is a risk that the text lines also can match, or a pattern that if more specific:
if ($line =~ /^\s*[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s*\r?\n$/) {


^ start of line
\s* any number of spaces
[0-9]+ at least one number
: a colon
[0-9]+ at least one number
\s* any number of spaces
\r? A possible windows end of line
\n a \n
$ the end.


\r?\n$ are all a subset of \s*.

Try this:
perl -pe 's/(^\d+:\d+)(\s*)(\r|\n)?$/\n$1, /'


It is unnecessary to capture optional whitespace plus optional line endings when you never use the captures. Also, \s* matches both optional whitespace and optional line endings. You might try using \K to keep the timestamp, instead of putting it back after. Also, lastly, why would you put back the line ending at the front? That would put blank lines into the file.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

this works until the time goes from to  59:53 to 1:00:06

I can't find subscribe button on any youtube clips but there must be something like "Download subscription" that produce better input file.
If you want to use sed for multiple-line structured input, it is a bit of a hassle to deal with:
<subscription.txt sed -E -n '
s/[[:space:]]+$//  # remove trailing whitespaces
/^[0-9:]+$/{       # if timestamp found,
    s/$/,/         # append ',' to the timestamp and
    x              # exchange current line and hold space
    1!{            # if it is not the 1st line,
        s/\n+/ /g  # remove all newlines and
        p          # print them
    }
    b              # skip rest of the script and go to next line
}
H                  # if the line is not timestamp, append it to hold space
${                 # at the bottom of file,
    x              # flush hold space
    s/\n+/ /g
    p
}'


The issue seems to be a space at the end of timestamp, try this :
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    die "Usage: $0 input_file output_file\n";
}
my ($input_file, $output_file) = @ARGV;
open(my $in, '<', $input_file) or die "Cannot open input file '$input_file': $!";
open(my $out, '>', $output_file) or die "Cannot open output file '$output_file': $!";
my $result = ''; 
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    if ($line =~ /^[0-9:]+$/) {
        # Line is a timestamp
        print $out "$result\n" if $result;
        $result = "$line,";
    } elsif ($line !~ /^$/) {
        # Line is text and is not empty
        $result .= " $line";
    }
}
print $out "$result\n";
close($in);
close($out);

print "Formatting complete. Output written to $output_file.\n";

